# $Re[f(x + n i)] = 0$ and $f(z)$ is not periodic

Tags: complex-analysis, recurrence-relations, big-list, dynamical-systems

Let $z$ be a complex number and $f(z)$ an entire function such that

For $x$ real and $n$ any integer.

$Re[f(x + n i)] = 0$ and $f(z)$ is not periodic.

What are typical examples of such $f(z)$ ? Is there a way to express the general solution ? Is it possible that there is an entire function $g(z)$ such that $g(f(x + ni)) = f(x + (n+1)i)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An entire function $f$ for which $f(x + n i) \in i \mathbb{R}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is necessarily periodic with period $2 i$. This follows from [Schwarz' reflection principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle).

Let $g_n(z) = i \, f(z + n i)$ then $g_n(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and according to this principle $g_n(\overline{z}) = \overline{g_n(z)}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.  For $n=0$ this shows that

$$
f(\overline{z}) = -\overline{f(z)}
$$

and for $n=1$ that

$$
f(\overline{z - i}) = f(\overline{z} + i) = -\overline{f(z + i)}.
$$

Combining these equalities we get

$$
\overline{f(z + i)} = -f(\overline{z - i}) = \overline{f(z - i)}
$$

and after substituting $z \leftarrow z + i$ and conjugation

$$
f(z + 2 i) = f(z).
$$.

Comment: Thanks. That really explains why I could not find any :)